# DVD won't play on Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS

Tags: 22.04, vlc, dvd

I have been able to watch DVD movies on my 20.04 LTS desktop for several years.  Just did an upgrade to jammy jellyfish and this no longer works.

The DVD player works fine with data files but when I try to open it in vlc it responds "no media found".

Did some research and I did do a

```
sudo apt install libdvdread8
```

With a legally purchased movie DVD, lshw gives:

```
*-cdrom
       description: DVD writer
       product: DVD_RW ND-3550A
       vendor: _NEC
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 1.05
       serial: [
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

With a Ubuntu ISO DVD:

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD writer
       product: DVD_RW ND-3550A
       vendor: _NEC
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       logical name: /media/cdrom
       version: 1.05
       serial: [
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          logical name: /media/cdrom
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8 signature=15f006ae state=mounted
```

syslog (note mount doesn’t implement content type guessing msg):

```
Aug 17 20:35:18 Office-Ubuntu gnome-shell[1594]: Unable to guess content types on added mount cdrom: Gio.IOErrorEnum: mount doesn’t implement content type guessing

Aug 17 20:35:18 Office-Ubuntu dbus-daemon[1489]: [session uid=1000 pid=1489] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.26' (uid=1000 pid=1594 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")

Aug 17 20:35:18 Office-Ubuntu dbus-daemon[1489]: [session uid=1000 pid=1489] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'

Aug 17 20:35:18 Office-Ubuntu nautilus[8050]: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Aug 17 20:36:10 Office-Ubuntu kernel: [16535.999541] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci

Aug 17 20:37:01 Office-Ubuntu systemd[1]: media-cdrom.mount: Deactivated successfully
```

.

No improvement.  Has something else changed?  I think the key to solving this is the fact that mount does not recognize the DVD's [possibly encrypted]  video format although I have reinstalled all of the required packages and they are now at the latest version.  I've tried several DVDs, all of which worked previously and work fine on other systems.

My basic problem seems to be that mount cannot read or guess what sort of video file(s) are on the DVD.  Mount can read and mount DVDs with garden variety ISO and data file structures.  I have done a reinstall of all related packages but may not have done so in the proper order.  I had to cobble a procedure from past answers on this forum as 22.04.1 is so new that a complete procedure is not available.  An answer that fixes the inability to recognize, mount and read a video DVD along with a complete start-to-finish updated procedure for running VLC to view video DVDs would be hugely helpful to me and to the community.

This may be a red herring but when I log in the GUI shows a floppy drive icon that was never there in previous versions on Ubuntu on this machine.  There has never been a floppy drive installed in this machine and there is no entry for it in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab.

Comment: Did you install `libdvd-pkg`?

Comment: libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.3-1-1).  As stated, DVDs have played fine on this machine for years.  The 22.04.01 upgrade broke it.

Comment: You might need to install `libdvdnav4` as well, and also might need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`.

Comment: libdvdnav4 is already the newest version (6.1.1-1).  Did a reconfigure (again) just because, before posting this question.

Comment: Then try removing all and reinstalling them.  I just did an upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04 and the DVDs still play, and these are the packages that playing DVDs rely on.  But anything that you have tried please add them to your question so that we are not guessing.

Comment: This upgrade failed and left the system in a broken state.  I was able to recover and it seems to be working ok except for this.  I did a full *dvd* install per the procedure on here as a first step.  At this point, Ubuntu doesn't even recognize the video DVD but data dvds work fine.

Comment: That's odd because there isn't that much difference between a data dvd and a video dvd?

I'm not sure if video dvds use a specific format but they should at least mount.

Comment: Try "sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg" and let it install libdvdcss2. Make sure this is legal in the country you're in (I think it's OK in the US and I'm almost certain France is OK with it, other countries might not be so accommodating, and double-check me even if you're in the US or France since you're dealing with DRM law here).

Comment: I am in the US.  As previously stated, I did a complete reinstall which included the step you listed.  Since I already let it install libdvd running reconfigure again just exited normally.  

I agree that even without those packages the DVD should at least mount.  Tried a USB DVD drive and that fails the same way.  So the problem seems to be something very basic.  Well, it does mount (sort of).  Just reports no media.

Comment: @jones0610 Do all DVDs behave this way? This sort of sounds like coincidental media failure.

Comment: Media is fine.  Tested them before posting my question.  I have a question about /etc/fstab though.  My other Ubuntu desktop with a DVD that works fine has no entry for sr0.  But it mounts to /media/username when a video DVD is installed.  On the machine in question I have a fstab entry /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom   Could be a red herring but I am baffled at this point.

Comment: `status=nodisk`... this sorta sounds like a device firmware problem to me. You can try removing that fstab entry (it sounds definitely out-of-place to me) and see how that helps. You might also boot back into Ubuntu 20.04 with a live USB and see if DVDs are recognized again there.

Comment: I did remove the sr0 entry in fstab a while ago.  No change.  I believe the problem is related to the syslog error message I highlighted in my question.  I'm quite certain the drives themselves are fine.  Going to 20.04 would likely create a new set of rathole problems to chase after.  I'd prefer to not play a guessing game and just fix 22.04.1.  I have two DVD drives.  Both give the same results.  The system (not the firmware) doesn't recognize video formats or even the file system on the DVDs.  Including unencrypted video DVDs.